# How can I pass the data from one listview into another listview located in a different form

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I need help.

How can I clone or pass the data from one listview into another listview located in another form using C#? The image from the left is the listview from the customer's main module and the listview from the right is for the confirmation module.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question yet, its a statement of intent

Answer (score 0):

Create a public Method in your form that you want to add data:

```
public void AddProduct(ListViewItem lvi)
{
     listview1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

now you can call this method from your other form:

```
frm2.AddProduct(lvi);
```

Of course as everthing on both listviews were identical, I chose this method to accept `ListViewItem` as parameter, you may want to send data as string or a class,...